# Transactions in Hosted Checkout Pages Test Mode are getting declined

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

So, I'm a reacquainting myself with PayPal's Hosted Checkout Pages, and I've set up my account to use Test Mode in PayPal Manager:
[image]

When testing a purchase, I request and get the secure token without issue, then redirect the user's browser to the hosted page.

At this stage, I've tried a few card numbers, including:

- 4111111111111111
- 4012888888881881
- Some Visa numbers generated [here](http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/).

So far, each attempt at a transaction results in the successful redirection to PayPal's site, where I enter some junk CC info.  When I click the purchase button, I always get the following error message:
"Error: There is a problem with your card. Please verify card details with your Bank."

Here's a screenshot of the error message:
[image]

When I search for any transactions in Test Mode, I actually see the transactions, all of which list "Declined" for the Response Message.

I've also turned off all the Fraud Protection filters for the Test Setup.

I don't know why they might be declining.  I'd appreciate any ideas.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait... Test Mode? Or do you mean Sandbox?

Comment: What I mean by "Test Mode" is that I set the Transaction Process Mode to "Test" instead of "Live" in Paypal Manager.  I'm a little unsure of Paypal's terminology in regards to what precisely Sandbox is and whether or not that's the same thing as what I'm referring to "Test Mode".

Comment: Sandbox is where you can test your various payments to PayPal. https://developer.paypal.com is where you can create Sandbox accounts and do testing.

Comment: Can you provide one of the declined transaction id (PNREF)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have kept this up-to-date... apologies for that, but a coworker solved this issue a day or so after posting this, and I forgot.  It turns out that test mode declines all transactions over $1999.99.  From https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1234&actp=LIST :

> The test servers are used to generate certain results for testing purposes, including a credit card being declined. Specific result codes can be generated by adding $1,000 to that result code. For example, for Result 13 (Referral), submit the amount $1,013. If the amount is in the range $1,000 to $1,999.99 but does not correspond to a supported result code, a result 12 (Decline) is returned instead. Any amount of $2,000.00 or over will also generate a result code 12 (Decline). The live servers do not have this limitation and can process transactions of up to $99,999.99.
>
> To post transactions to the live servers, you will need to change the endpoint in the API, application, or shopping cart. Click here for more information.

The moral of the story:  If you're just trying to test a basic transaction, keep it under $1000.